# Method to set internal variable equal to array length

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've programmt an Object in Javascript which looks like that:

```js
var facebookFriends={
    name: "Ilias",
    friendsArray:["john", "anna"],
    friends:"",
    setFriends:function(){
 friends=friendsArray.length
    },
};
```

When I call the function I get the following error which I can't understand.

```
VM52:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: friendsArray is not defined
    at Object.setFriends (<anonymous>:6:2)
    at <anonymous>:1:17
```

Can anyone explain why is this happening, since the array is defined?
Somehow it seems that the function is not compiled before it is called.

**EDIT:**

The initial problem is solved but now I came up with a new idea:
what about initialising the variable without a setter method:

```js
var facebookFriends={
    name: "Ilias",
    friendsArray:["john", "anna"],
    friends:"",
    friends:this.friendsArray.length,
};
```

Now comes an another error:

```
VM51:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:5:31
```

Comment: `this.friends=this.friendsArray.length` should be work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access both the properties (`friendsArray` and `friends`) with `this`

```
setFriends : function(){
    this.friends = this.friendsArray.length
},
```

**Demo**

```js
var facebookFriends={
    name: "Ilias",
    friendsArray:["john", "anna"],
    friends:"",
    setFriends:function(){
    this.friends=this.friendsArray.length
    },
};

console.log( "before invoking setFriends ",facebookFriends.friends);
facebookFriends.setFriends();
console.log( "after invoking setFriends ",facebookFriends.friends);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference the property of the object using `this`.

```js
var facebookFriends={
    name: "Ilias",
    friendsArray:["john", "anna"],
    friends:"",
    setFriends:function(){
         this.friends=this.friendsArray.length;
    },
};

facebookFriends.setFriends();
console.log(facebookFriends.friends);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var facebookFriends ={
    name : "Ilias",
    friendsArray : ["john", "anna"],
    friends : "",
    setFriends:function(){
     this.friends = this.friendsArray.length
    },
};

facebookFriends.setFriends();
console.log(facebookFriends.friends);
```

Answer (score 0):

The property `friendsArray` is not defined as a variable. You defined `facebookFriends` as variable. By writing `facebookFriends.friendsArray`, you can access the property of the variable `facebookFriends`. Furthermore, your `setFriends` function should look like the following:

```
var facebookFriends={
    name: "Ilias",
    friendsArray:["john", "anna"],
    friends:"",
    setFriends:function(){
        friends = facebookFriends.friendsArray.length
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.friendsArray` or the Object name `facebookFriends.friendsArray` should work

```
var facebookFriends={
name: "Ilias",
friendsArray:["john", "anna"],
friends:"",
setFriends:function(){
friends= this.friendsArray.length //or facebookFriends.friendsArray.length
},
```

};